# Unable to process password variable in powershell because of special characters

Tags: powershell, passwords

I am working on a PS script to install VSTS agents on my Azure VMs through an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline.

Here in the below script, I am passing a Service Account Password, which is set by my customers. Below script fails whenever Password consist of special characters like

> ")';:(

Code:

```
 .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname DeployGroupSQL --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --windowsLogonAccount $(ServiceAccountUser) 
--windowsLogonPassword **"$(Service_Account_Password)"** --work '_work' 
--adddeploymentgrouptags --deploymentgrouptags $SQL 
--url 'https://dev.azure.com/campusmgmt-product-development/' 
--projectname 'Student' --auth PAT --token u4bq6j******************************bhhyq;
```

I have tried putting whole password into double quotes as well as single quotes but of no help.

This Service Account Password is a Pipeline variable and hence needs to be passed like $(Service_Account_Password).

Can you please suggest on how can I deal with this situation. I have already tried putting this as a here-string, Secure-String, or script parameter but has not proved of any help.

Hoping to hear back soon as this is urgent for my project release.

Comment: You need to escape the special characters, see here https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html